# JQuery Validation По нажатию кнопки

Tags: php, jquery

Доброго времени суток! Как сделать валидацию формы только по нажатию кнопки с помощью jquery validation, а то при изменении поля он сразу же проверяет его.
Код валидатора:

```
$("form[id='loginform']").validate({
  rules:{

        email:{
            required: true,
            email: true,
            minlength: 4,
            maxlength: 36,
        },

        password:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 36,
              remote: {
                url: "index.php?route=account/login/validatex",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                  email: function() {
                    return $( "#email" ).val();
                  },
                  password: function() {
                    return $( "#password" ).val();
                  }
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response == true){
                        // $("#btnlogin").click(function(){ 
                        //  window.location.href = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname+"/index.php?route=account/account";
                        // }); 
                    }else{
                        alert('Логин или пароль не верны');
                    }
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }

              }
        },

   },

   messages:{

        email:{
            required: "обязательно для заполнения",
            email:"введите корректную почту",
            minlength: "e-mail должен быть минимум 4 символа",
            maxlength: "максимальное число символо - 36",
        },

        password:{
            required: "обязательно для заполнения",
            minlength: "пароль должен быть минимум 6 символов",
            maxlength: "максимальное число символо - 36",
            remote: "логин или пароль не верны",
        },

   }});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением remote в новый метод

```
var validatePassStatus = null;
jQuery.validator
.addMethod(
    'validatePass',
    function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php?route=account/login/validatex",
            async: false,
            type: 'post',
                    data: {
                      email: function() {
                        return $( "#email" ).val();
                      },
                      password: function() {
                        return $( "#password" ).val();
                      }
                    },
            success: function(data)
            {
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data == 'true'){

                        }else{
                validatePassStatus = data.status;
                        }
            },
            complete: function(){},
            error: function(){}
        });
        return true;
    },
    jQuery.validator.format("Неверный пароль")
);
$("form[id='loginform']").validate({
      rules:{

            email:{
                required: true,
                email: true,
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 36,
            },

            password:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 36,
                validatePass: "",
            },

       },

       messages:{

            email:{
                required: "обязательно для заполнения",
                email:"введите корректную почту",
                minlength: "e-mail должен быть минимум 4 символа",
                maxlength: "максимальное число символо - 36",
            },

            password:{
                required: "обязательно для заполнения",
                minlength: "пароль должен быть минимум 6 символов",
                maxlength: "максимальное число символо - 36",
                validatePass: "Неверный пароль",
            },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }

       }
});
```